# PHP push new key and value in existing object array

Tags: php, arrays, object, push

In my study how objects and arrays work with PHP I have a new problem. Searching in existing questions didn't give myself the right "push".

I have this for example:

```
$html_doc = (object) array
    (
    "css"   => array(),
    "js"    => array()
    );
array_push($html_doc , "title" => "testtitle");
```

Why is this not working? Do i need to specify first the key title? Or is there another "1 line" solution?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

array_push() doesn't allow you to specify keys, only values: use

```
$html_doc["title"] = "testtitle";
```

.... except you're not working with an array anyway, because you're casting that array to an object, so use

```
$html_doc->title = "testtitle";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `$html_doc["title"] = "testtitle";`

Check [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php#108118) on the array_push manual page.