# PHP push array in array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, object, echo

Related to my previous question [PHP push new key and value in existing object array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23916521/php-push-new-key-and-value-in-existing-object-array)

I have now this situation:

```
$html_doc = (object) array
    (
    "css"       => array(),
    "js"        => array(),
    "body"  => 
        array
            (
            array
               (
               "page"   => "error"
               ),
            array
               (
               "controller" => "adminpanel"
               ),
            ),  
    );
```

With a foreach construct I get what I want, when the body key is a page I can do what I want and when the body key is a controller also.

But if I start like this:

```
$html_doc = (object) array
    (
    "css"       => array(),
    "js"        => array(),
    "body"      => array()
    );
```

**question 1**
How can I add (I prefer one line if possible) after this a key page with value error and for example at an other place in my code page with value contact? Ofcourse I tried a lot things what looks for me logical, but no result.

**question 2**
Like I said above, with a foreach I get what I want, but if I want to echo for example body with keyindex 0, how do I do that? I tried for example:

```
 echo $html_doc->body[0]["controller"];
```

But I dont get it displayed. Only when I the foreach loop. What am I doing this time wrong?

**edit @Feroz Akbar**

Answering your question in comments wasn't a big success, I didn't know the mark-up works different then here, and I had only 5 minutes to edit my comment and to find out. My output now is this:

```
    if (isset($html_doc->body))
        {
        foreach ($html_doc->body as $location => $body_content) 
            {
            if ($location === "controller")
                include(_PAGES_DIR_ . $html_doc->controller . "/php/" . $body_content . "_body.php");
            else
                include(_WEBSITE_DIR_ . "body/" . $location . "/" . $body_content . "_body.php");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try $html[index_of_your_array] in push.

like

array_push ($html_doc[1], $valueToPush);

Comment: how you want the output look like

Comment: `foreach ($html_doc->body as $location => $body_content)   {
if ($location === "controller")
    include(_PAGES_DIR_ . $html_doc->controller . "/php/" . $body_content . "_body.php");
else
    include(_WEBSITE_DIR_ . "body/" . $location . "/" . $body_content . "_body.php");
}`  **forgive me, I don't know how I can mark-up in comments**