# Codeigniter Add new key and value to object(stdClass) inside foreach loop

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to add another key and value to the an array inside the foreach loop.
I have the following array.

```
    array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[27]
      public 'ID' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'sectiontitle' => string 'Personal Information' (length=20)
      public 'field_format' => string 'vertical' (length=8)
      public 'status' => string '1' (length=1)
```

and the php code

```
       foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
         }
        var_dump($data);
        return $data;
```

i would like to add key [fields] and value string to it.

Comment: Why not you use `foreach ($query->result() as $key=>$value) {`

Comment: I did try that, it didn't work, could you give me an example please

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP push new key and value in existing object array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23916521/php-push-new-key-and-value-in-existing-object-array)

Comment: @Uchicha That is from out side of the foreach loop i am trying to add the new key value at the end of current loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $row->newKey = $newValue;
                $data[] = $row;
             }
            var_dump($data);
            return $data;
```