# Take an ID from an array, find it in an array of objects and push the value to array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, mapping

I have an Array called `$formAnswers` and an Array of Objects called `$defaultData`.

I need to take the `[Id]` from `$formAnswers` and find in `$defaultData` to get the particular content block. Then check `[InputKeyName]` from `$formAnswers` in the content block and push the `[Value]`  from `$formAnswers` to `$defaultData`.

- There can be the same `[Id]` multiple times in `$formAnswers`.
- In `$defaultData` one `[Id]` will be only occur once.

Till the `for` loop everything works as expected but from there it's not working. How do I solve this problem?

**Here is my function**:

```
public function pushFormAnswersToDefaultData(array $defaultData, array $formAnswers) 
{
  foreach ($defaultData["info"] as $defaultDataContent) 
  {   
    foreach ($defaultDataContent as $defaultDataProfile) 
    {      
      if (is_array($defaultDataProfile)) 
      {        
        foreach ($defaultDataProfile as $defaultKey => $defaultDataProfileContent) 
        { 
          //Content Block         
          for($c=0;$c<count($formAnswers);$c++) 
          {        
          if($defaultDataProfileContent->Id == $formAnswers[$c]['Id']) 
          {              
            foreach ($defaultDataProfile[$defaultKey] as $nameKey => $profileDataContentInside) 
            {               
              if ($nameKey == $formAnswers[$c]['InputKeyName']) 
              {                 
                $defaultDataProfileContent->$formAnswers[$c]['InputKeyName'] = $formAnswers[$c]['Value'];              
              }             
            }            
          }         
        }       
        }      
      }    
    }  
  }
  return $defaultData;
}
```

**Here is `$formAnswers`**:

```
  $formAnswers = Array (

      [0] => Array
          (
              [Id] => 0142643741
              [InputKeyName] => FromDate
              [Value] => 28.03.2017
          )

      [1] => Array
          (
              [Id] => 5338820142
              [InputKeyName] => Menu
              [Value] => Green Salad
          )

      [2] => Array
          (
              [Id] => 7351265992
              [InputKeyName] => Area
              [Value] => Mc Cully Green
          )

      [3] => Array
          (
              [Id] => 02643029354
              [InputKeyName] => Menu
              [Value] => Fried Rice
          )

      [4] => Array
          (
              [Id] => 9808392996
              [InputKeyName] => Description
              [Value] => Bolognese is super easy and a true classic Italian pasta 
          )

      [5] => Array
          (
              [Id] => 02643029354
              [InputKeyName] => FromDate
              [Value] => 04.01.2017
          )
  )
```

**Here is `$defaultData`**:

```
  $defaultData = Array
  (
      [info] => Array
          (
              [0] => stdClass Object
                  (
                      [__type] => customerDEDto:#Profile
                      [ArchieBurns] => Array
                          (
                              [0] => stdClass Object
                                  (
                                      [Id] => 2987279348
                                      [Description] => fgdfdfg
                                      [FromDate] => 01.05.2016
                                      [Area] => Murwillubah Trail
                                      [ToDate] => 01.08.2016
                                  )

                              [1] => stdClass Object
                                  (
                                      [Id] => 7593862202
                                      [Menu] => CHICKEN FREESTYLE WRAP
                                      [FromDate] => 01.05.2016
                                      [Area] => South Jaybarry Gardens
                                      [ToDate] => 01.08.2016
                                  )

                          )

                      [TheoRobertson] => Array
                          (
                              [0] => stdClass Object
                                  (
                                      [Id] => 6491059338
                                      [Description] => khjkh
                                      [FromDate] => 01.05.2016
                                      [Area] => Murwillubah Trail
                                      [ToDate] => 01.08.2016
                                  )

                              [1] => stdClass Object
                                  (
                                      [Id] => 6448295430
                                      [Menu] => HEY PESTO! PIZZA
                                      [FromDate] => 01.05.2016
                                      [Area] => South Clock Barn
                                      [ToDate] => 01.08.2016
                                  )
    
                          )

                      [ChristopherParry] => Array
                          (
                              [0] => stdClass Object
                                  (
                                      [Id] => 9808392996
                                      [Description] => asdad
                                      [FromDate] => 01.05.2016
                                      [Area] => Murwillubah Trail
                                      [ToDate] => 01.08.2016
                                  )

                              [1] => stdClass Object
                                  (
                                      [Id] => 4701327370
                                      [Menu] => PIZZA FRESCO
                                      [FromDate] => 01.05.2016
                                      [Area] => South Jaybarry Gardens
                                      [ToDate] => 01.08.2016
                                  )

                          )

                      [EdwardRose] => Array
                          (
                              [0] => stdClass Object
                                  (
                                      [Id] => 9261501733
                                      [Description] => fghfg
                                      [FromDate] => 01.05.2016
                                      [Area] => Murwillubah Trail
                                      [ToDate] => 01.08.2016
                                  )

                              [1] => stdClass Object
                                  (
                                      [Id] => 9064113070
                                      [Menu] => CHICKEN FREESTYLE WRAP
                                      [FromDate] => 01.05.2016
                                      [Area] => South Jaybarry Gardens
                                      [ToDate] => 01.08.2016
                                  )
                          )

                      [CoreyWest] => Array
                          (
                              [0] => stdClass Object
                                  (
                                      [Id] => 7434455815
                                      [Description] => ewrwr
                                      [FromDate] => 01.05.2016
                                      [Area] => Murwillubah Trail
                                      [ToDate] => 01.08.2016
                                  )

                              [1] => stdClass Object
                                  (
                                      [Id] => 8740648411
                                      [Menu] => Pancakes
                                      [FromDate] => 01.05.2016
                                      [Area] => South Bacton Grove
                                      [ToDate] => 01.08.2016
                                  )

                          )

                      [Language] => de
                      [ProfileId] => jkl-3541682444-x01
                      [ThiagoBird] => Array
                          (
                              [0] => stdClass Object
                                  (
                                      [Id] => 6810891812
                                      [Description] => jkljkl
                                      [FromDate] => 01.05.2016
                                      [Area] => Murwillubah Trail
                                      [ToDate] => 01.08.2016
                                  )

                              [1] => stdClass Object
                                  (
                                      [Id] => 02643029354
                                      [Menu] => Spaghetti
                                      [FromDate] => 01.05.2016
                                      [Area] => Moslee Grade Northeast
                                      [ToDate] => 01.08.2016
                                  )

                          )

                  )

              [1] => stdClass Object
                  (
                      [__type] => customerENDto:#Profile
                      [ArchieBurns] => Array
                          (
                              [0] => stdClass Object
                                  (
                                      [Id] => 1682400506
                                      [Description] => werner
                                      [FromDate] => 01.05.2016
                                      [Area] => Murwillubah Trail
                                      [ToDate] => 01.08.2016
                                  )

                              [1] => stdClass Object
                                  (
                                      [Id] => 7814641591
                                      [Menu] => Waffles
                                      [FromDate] => 01.05.2016
                                      [Area] => Launch Quay
                                      [ToDate] => 01.08.2016
                                  )

                          )

                      [TheoRobertson] => Array
                          (
                              [0] => stdClass Object
                                  (
                                      [Id] => 7351265992
                                      [Description] => high
                                      [FromDate] => 01.05.2016
                                      [Area] => Murwillubah Trail
                                      [ToDate] => 01.08.2016
                                  )

                              [1] => stdClass Object
                                  (
                                      [Id] => 2467265927
                                      [Menu] => goose
                                      [FromDate] => 01.05.2016
                                      [Area] => South Savine Quadrant
                                      [ToDate] => 01.08.2016
                                  )

                          )

                      [ChristopherParry] => Array
                          (
                              [0] => stdClass Object
                                  (
                                      [Id] => 9066762572
                                      [Description] => hfghfg
                                      [FromDate] => 01.05.2016
                                      [Area] => Murwillubah Trail
                                      [ToDate] => 01.08.2016
                                  )

                              [1] => stdClass Object
                                  (
                                      [Id] => 5338820142
                                      [Menu] => CHICKEN FREESTYLE WRAP
                                      [FromDate] => 01.05.2016
                                      [Area] => Hughenden Alley
                                      [ToDate] => 01.08.2016
                                  )

                          )

                      [EdwardRose] => Array
                          (
                              [0] => stdClass Object
                                  (
                                      [Id] => 6594908359
                                      [Description] => trzrtz
                                      [FromDate] => 01.05.2016
                                      [Area] => Murwillubah Trail
                                      [ToDate] => 01.08.2016
                                  )

                              [1] => stdClass Object
                                  (
                                      [Id] => 0075490683
                                      [Menu] => French dip
                                      [FromDate] => 01.05.2016
                                      [Area] => Heustis Plaza
                                      [ToDate] => 01.08.2016
                                  )                 
                          )

                      [CoreyWest] => Array
                          (
                              [0] => stdClass Object
                                  (
                                      [Id] => 0142643741
                                      [Description] => dfsdf
                                      [FromDate] => 01.05.2016
                                      [Area] => Murwillubah Trail
                                      [ToDate] => 01.08.2016
                                  )

                              [1] => stdClass Object
                                  (
                                      [Id] => 6165554440
                                      [Menu] => CHICKEN FREESTYLE WRAP
                                      [FromDate] => 01.05.2016
                                      [Area] => East Otterburn Heights
                                      [ToDate] => 01.08.2016
                                  )
                          )

                      [Language] => en
                      [ProfileId] => mzd-d95840ec4559
                      [ThiagoBird] => Array
                          (
                              [0] => stdClass Object
                                  (
                                      [Id] => 1905649736
                                      [Description] => rsfsr
                                      [FromDate] => 01.05.2016
                                      [Area] => Murwillubah Trail
                                      [ToDate] => 01.08.2016
                                  )

                              [1] => stdClass Object
                                  (
                                      [Id] => 4580348850
                                      [Menu] => eggrolls
                                      [FromDate] => 01.05.2016
                                      [Area] => Shorthills Crescent
                                      [ToDate] => 01.08.2016
                                  )

                          )

                  )

          )

  )
```

Comment: This needs serious work... Clean it up!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Please don't copy paste from editors such as MS Word. Use regular quotes, not fancy quotes. Also, select your code fragments and use Ctrl + K to format it nicely. See the link above to know more. If you post your future questions in the same format, it will not be legible for anyone, and the chances of your question being answered will be very minimal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP push new key and value in existing object array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23916521/php-push-new-key-and-value-in-existing-object-array)

Comment: This question does not have a [mcve] because there is no clear expression of the desired result.  This makes it harder for reviewers to validate/judge answers let alone allow volunteers to contribute with answers.